# How to fix "RIGHT in T2 type *N not found" in SQL Server reading from AS400?

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I am joining two files that reside on AS400 in an SSIS package. I am using ODBC Source and SQL command text field.

The SQL query against each table works well and populates data. Even when I join them, it works fine EXCEPT when the "RIGHT" function is there.

This query works fine:

```
SQL
SELECT
T1.DOC,
T1.DOCNUM,
T1.REF4
FROM SCHEMA.Table1 AS T1
```

This one also works fine:

```
SELECT
T2.YEAR,
T2.PERIOD
FROM SCHEMA.Table2 AS T2
```

Even this works well:

```
SELECT
T1.DOC,
T1.DOCNUM,
T1.REF4,
T2.YEAR,
T2.PERIOD
FROM SCHEMA.Table1 AS T1
INNER JOIN SCHEMA.Table2 AS T2
ON T1.DOCNUM=T2.DOCNUM
```

But when I have the RIGHT function in the query (below), it errors out:

```
SELECT
T1.DOC,
T1.DOCNUM,
T1.REF4,
T1.RIGHT(REF4, 8) as REF5,
T2.YEAR,
T2.PERIOD
FROM SCHEMA.Table1 AS T1
INNER JOIN SCHEMA.Table2 AS T2
ON T1.DOCNUM=T2.DOCNUM
```

I expect the query to capture the 8 right characters of REF4, but I get the following error:

**Error at Data Flow Task TEST open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error 
occurred. state: '4292'. Native Error Code: -2N. fl8MISystem i Access
ODBC DriverlD82 for i5/OS)SQL0204 -  RIGHT in T1 type 'N not found.**

Comment: I don't think a syntax error is necessarily a simple typographical error. It could be a conceptual error as described in the correct answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
RIGHT(T1.REF4, 8) as REF5
```

`T1` qualifies the *column name*, not the function name.

Comment: I knew it was something very basic that I was missing. Thanks a lot for your help.